# How to install hedgewars 0.9.15?

Tags: software-installation

The new year is near and new version of Hedgewars was realased.
[Link for Download](http://www.hedgewars.org/download.html)

There is packages for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X but no for Ubuntu, like .deb. I just want to ask how to install it on Ubuntu. There is source code available. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hedgewars 0.9.15 will be available from playdeb in a few hours (it's currently synchronizing to other mirrors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile it yourself from the Source Code available in the official webpage OR wait for playdeb to have it ready which takes a couple of days.

Here is the link http://www.playdeb.net/software/Hedgewars

And the steps are:

1. Go to : http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/10.10/#how_to_install

Follow the instructions there.

1. Go to: http://www.playdeb.net/updates/ubuntu/10.10/?q=hedgewars

Click on **Install this Now**

Wait for it to install then go to the Main Meny -> Games

Enjoy.

Of course adding the PPA from playdeb will notify you when the latest version 0.9.15 comes out and you can update like you normally update any other program.

you can help playdeb by notifying the Devs over there that HedgeWar 0.9.15 has come out so they can start working on the deb version as soon as they can.

Comment: Requests for packaging are made as bugs on the Launchpad site for GetDeb. [Here is the bug for this version of Hedgewars](https://bugs.launchpad.net/getdeb.net/+bug/695098). You can mark it as affecting you.

Comment: And that was a [duplicate of this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/getdeb.net/+bug/694941), which has just been fixed - it is now available from the getdeb repositories.

Comment: Holy mother dv3500ea you are fast. how can i give +1 to a comment?
Nvm just saw it.